# Sencha Touch do not set scale and allow scrolling and resize on iPhone or iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, extjs, sencha-touch

I am playing around with Sencha Touch, especially with examples like http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/

However I am faced with a problem, when using the component the scale is set on the iPhone and the user cannot scroll the page or zoom in or out.

How may I disable these settings as I would like to have the carousel on a page which can be scrolled, and zoomed in/out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Sencha person] You can't zoom in or out of a Sencha component. Having fixed UI Chrome is one of the reasons to even use a UI framework (otherwise you'd might use a simple mobile-optimized web page).

You can have a scrollable area within a carousel, but you might want to consider whether that's really the best UX, since the carousel is already a scroller (it just scrolls in fixed increments) Take a look at touchstyle.mobi/app for an example of a data-store backed carousel.

Comment: why would one design a UI framework to negatively impact accessibility in a manner such as this?

Comment: Sencha Touch 2.0 and 2.1 don't have WAI_ARIA support.

Comment: Thanks for catching this Dave, I'll remove my comment

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it seems to me that the goal of sencha is to make full screen apps, so it seems logical that you cannot zoom/scroll the page ?

Comment: Possibly. Then there would be no possibility to have for example: http://www.htc.com/uk but with the carousel controllable by swipes.

Answer (score 0):

There are methods and plugins for zooming if you want.

[Carousel ImageViewer (plugin) - Zoom feature](https://github.com/SunboX/ST2_ImageViewer)

[Pinch-to-zoom in panels](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246974-Pinch-to-Zoom-Panels-with-HTML)

[Pinch emulator (plugin)](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/pinch-emulator-plugin-for-sencha-touch)