# Sencha - Disabling Sencha Events

Tags: ios, events, extjs

i want to remove the Event-Handlers from Sencha Touch, so that zooming in Mobile Safari works (Currently blocked by Sencha).
Is there any solution for my Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha touch relies on the viewport not being zoomable. The entire layout engine is based on the assumption that the viewport is the size of the screen. You can listen for your own pinch event and zoom some part of the UI that you choose to fix

[Sencha Touch do not set scale and allow scrolling and resize on iPhone or iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700058/sencha-touch-do-not-set-scale-and-allow-scrolling-and-resize-on-iphone-or-ipad)

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?174008-How-to-Enable-Pinch-Zoom-to-HTML-content

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?163059-Native-Zoom

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-suspendEvents

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-resumeEvents

Comment: Those may help to suspend events, which supposedly is what the OP asked, but won't allow zooming with sencha